# Nodes containing simple field collection not displaying properly

Tags: entities

I have a content type to which I added fields like description, image and a field collection containing two simple text fields. Editing and viewing in the backend (logged in as admin) works properly. But when I log off and go to the node it just shows the title and no more. Can anybody lead me to the right direction to find the error?

EDIT: If I leave the field collection fields empty, the other fields get displayed to other users, if I fill in something nothing shows up, just the title

Comment: what about authenticated user none admins?

Comment: also does not show up for authenticated users

Comment: did you install any special permission module?

Comment: I am not using any special permission module

Comment: Can this be caused by entity reference? The content types also contain an entity reference field.

Comment: Enityt Reference is not causing the error, I tried it with another content type, same result: just showing up for the superadmin

Comment: I switched to the standard theme and the field collection and everything show up fine, so I will take a look into the template files.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the answer, but not really the solution. I deleted the following code in my node.tpl which caused the malfunctioning of field collection:

```
<?php if (!empty($content['links'])): ?>
<nav class="links node-links clearfix"><?php print render($content['links']); ?></nav>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But I do not understand why.